# Wirtschaftswissenschaft vs. Ökonomie

Tags: meaning, scientific-language

Most dictionaries give the meaning "Economy" for the word "Wirtschaft" (and "Economical science" for the word "Wirtschaftswissenschaft").

In English speaking universities we have two separate fields namely "Business Management" and "Economics" (which cover totally different topics). But in German speaking universities they both seem to be referred as "Wirtschaftswissenschaft" (possibly with BWL and VWL branches?).

So what is the difference between the words "Wirtschaftswissenschaft" and "Ökonomie" ? Is the first one equal to "Management" and the second one equal to the "Economical science"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent misunderstanding, 'Ökonomie' is rather used for *economy* than for *economics*, 'Wirtschaftswissenschaft' (synonym to 'Volkwirtschaftslehre', sometimes also 'Ökonomik') means *economics*, while the plural 'Wirtschaftswissenschaft**en**' at universities regularly mean a combination of 'Betriebswirtschaftslehre (BWL)' - *business management* and 'Volkswirtschaftslehre (VWL)'.

Answer (score 5):

If you look up both words in Duden, you'll find:

- [Wirtschaftswissenschaft](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wirtschaftswissenschaft):

  > Wissenschaft, die sich (als Betriebs-, Volkswirtschaftslehre, Finanzwissenschaft) mit der Wirtschaft beschäftigt
- [Ökonomie](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Oekonomie):

  > Wirtschaftswissenschaft, -theorie

But Ökonomie does also mean

> Wirtschaft, wirtschaftliche Struktur (eines bestimmten Gebiets)

which does translate to "economy".

Answer (score 3):

“Wirtschaftswissenschaft” is one of many words that were invented in the 19th or 20th century as a substitute for an established Greek or Latin borrowing, in this case for “Ökonomie”. Basically in the same category as “Fernsprecher” as a replacement for “Telefon”. The meaning is in either case the same.

Answer (score 0):

You normally would say *Wirtschaftswissenschaft* but *Ökonomie* is also possible. They have the same meaning. But *Ökonomie* is a bit old-fashioned. A better one would be *Ökonomik*.

If you want to begin studying, you can chose between BWL and VWL. Both are subcategories of *Wirtschaftswissenschaft*. In colloquial speech people often use BWL as a synonym to *Wirtschaftswissenschaft*.

If you want to call a economist, you can say *Ökonom*. It’s more often used than *Wirtschaftswissenschaftler*.

See also Wikipedia:

> Die Wirtschaftswissenschaft, auch Ökonomik und veraltend Ökonomie, ist die Wissenschaft von der Wirtschaft (Ökonomie). Die Wirtschaftswissenschaft untersucht den rationalen Umgang mit Gütern, die nur beschränkt verfügbar sind.

Answer (score 0):

In German, *Ökonomie* can mean **both** the thing ("economy") and the science about the thing ("economical science") - Just like "Mathematics". Additionally, the efficient usage of resources can also be referred to with *Ökonomie*

*Wirtschaftswissenschaft* obviously only refers to the science, in this respect, it is used synonymously to *Ökonomie* (but this can be considered aging).

> Im Interesse der Ökonomie bitten wir darum, die Fenster in klimatisierten Räumen stets geschlossen zu halten
>
> Die Regierung ergriff Maßnahmen, um die Ökonomie des Landes zu stützen
>
> Ökonomie ist ein wichtiges Fach für Betriebswirtschaftler

An outdated usage for *Ökonomie* also used to simply refer to an *agricultural enterprise*, i.e. a large Farm.

Comment: Ich denke, dass der Vergleich zur Mathematik die Sache ein bisschen veunklart. Denn die Mathematik hat ja keinen außerhalb ihrer selbst liegenden Gegenstand.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Mathematik bezeichnet genauso eine Wissenschaft wie die Tätigkeit - man denke nur an einen Versicherungsmathematiker